# How can I save the -ls output to hdfs directory

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, command-line

```
hadoop fs -ls /

drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop professor           0 2018-03-12 06:51 /dir1
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-04-04 09:02 /dir2
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop hadoop              0 2018-04-04 05:55 /dir3
drwx------   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-03-12 07:01 /tmp
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop hadoop              0 2018-03-18 03:49 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-04-04 08:36 /photo
```

I want to save the ls result in hdfs directory 
and I have tried below command.
    `hadoop fs -ls / > / lsResult.txt`
    `hadoop fs -ls / > lsResult.txt`
    `hadoop fs -ls / > hadoop fs / lsResult.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect, you are interacting with your **LOCAL** filesystem.
To save to HDFS you need to do a HDFS put.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls / > lsResult.txt
$ hadoop fs -put lsResult.txt /
```